# Show/hide control nav on flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider

I'm using flexslider on a new website, but i need to make the control-nav (bullets below slider) appear invisible by default, fade in when the mouse is hovering the slider and fade out when mouse leaves the slider area, just like the direction-nav buttons.

How can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="flexslider_here">
```

```
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#flexslider').hide();

$("#flexslider_here").mouseenter(function() {
$('#flexslider').show();
   });

  $("#flexslider_here").mouseleave(function() {

  $('#flexslider').hide();
 });


)};
</script>
```